# How to make a Common legend for multiple plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make a Common legend for multiple plots? As I have plotted multiple plots but each plot is showing a single legend for itself as if I  want to remove it and show a command legend.

And I also want to rename xlim to lon and ylim = lat. How can it be possible in image.plot?

This is my code

```
     set.panel()
     par(oma=c( 0,0,0,4)) # margin of 4 spaces width at right hand side
     set.panel( 2,2) # 2X2 matrix of plots

     # now draw all your plots using usual image command
    for (  k in 1:4){
   image.plot(lon, lat, pr2)
    plot(shape,add=TRUE)  
  image.plot(lon, lat, pr1)

      plot(shape,add=TRUE)

  }

    par(oma=c( 0,0,0,1))# reset margin to be much smaller.
   image.plot( legend.only=TRUE, zlim=c(0,2000),horizontal = TRUE)
```

image.plot tricked into  plotting in margin of old setting

```
set.panel() #
```

This is my image showing the plot:

[image]

Comment: Did you consider using ggplot2 and facet_wrap https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html? This typically draws just one legend.

Comment: As I am in not use to ggplot2? I will try it ones. If possible can anyone modify in the above code, so it can be easier for me.